# Run secondcrack in a nginx server

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I am trying to run [secondcrack](https://github.com/marcoarment/secondcrack) that is a php solution to A static-file Markdown blogging engine in a nginx server (the original was only tested in Apache). So does anybody know how to convert this Apaches's .htaccess to nginx syntax?

```
Options -MultiViews

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css text/javascript text/xml text/rss text/rss+xml

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^\.]*)$ - [T=text/html]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here we go:

```
index index.html
location ~ ^/your_blog_location/. {
    default_type text/html;
    try_files $uri $uri.html;
    error_page    404 = /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 = /500.html;
}
```

(**dont forget** --> restart nginx once these is done)